# Putting element into root node after matching lower node

Tags: xml, xslt

I used some code in the forum to wrap a number of child nodes within a node, but now I am struggling to get a heading into the root node. Here is an example of the xml I want to convert:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<A>
    <B>
        <C>stuff</C>
        <D>stuff1</D>
        <E>stuff2</E>
    </B>
    <B>
        <C>stuff3</C>
        <D>stuff4</D>
        <E>stuff5</E>
    </B>
</A>
```

and this is what I require:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<A>
    <H>heading</H>
    <B>
        <C>stuff</C>
        <ExtraInfo>
            <D>stuff</D>
            <E>stuff2</E>
        </ExtraInfo>
    </B>
    <B>
        <C>stuff3</C>
        <ExtraInfo>
            <D>stuff4</D>
            <E>stuff5</E>
        <ExtraInfo>
    </B>
</A>
```

This is the xsl I use:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ex="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times"  extension-element-prefixes="ex">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="B/*"/>
        <xsl:template match="B/C">
            <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="B/*[not(self::C )][1]">

            <ExtraInfo>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="D/*"
                                     mode="ExtraInfo"/>
                                     <D><xsl:value-of select="//D"/></D>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="E/*"
                                     mode="ExtraInfo"/>
                                     <E><xsl:value-of select="//E"/></E>

            </ExtraInfo>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="B/*" mode="ExtraInfo">
            <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

and this is the result:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
- <A>
- <B>
  <C>stuff</C> 
- <ExtraInfo>
  <D>stuff1</D> 
  <E>stuff2</E> 
  </ExtraInfo>
  </B>
- <B>
  <C>stuff3</C> 
- <ExtraInfo>
  <D>stuff1</D> 
  <E>stuff2</E> 
  </ExtraInfo>
  </B>
  </A>
```

If I try to put in a template for the root node, I get an error telling me that I can't have 2 higher level elements, or some such. How can I insert the header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a template for the `A` element i.e.

```
<xsl:template match="A">
  <xsl:copy>
    <H>Heading</H>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks very much, that worked, but I just noticed that under the node <C>stuff3</C> I should be getting "stuff4" and "stuff5" not "stuff1" and "stuff2". I wonder if you see what the problem there is?

Comment: Well the `<D><xsl:value-of select="//D"/></D>` is wrong, you rather want to use `<D><xsl:value-of select="../D"/></D>`. The same for the `<E><xsl:value-of select="//E"/></E>`. On the other hand the whole code in that template looks a bit convoluted to me, I would rather write a template matching `B` that then applies templates to `C`, outputs the wrapper elements `ExtraInfo` and populates that by applying templates to `D` and `E`: `<xsl:template match="B"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="C"/><ExtraInfo><xsl:apply-templates select="D | E"/></ExtraInfo></xsl:copy></xsl:template>`.

Comment: I know. I am only new to this stuff, and feeling my way around. Are there any good tutorials you would recommend? The w3c is a bit basic and the rules are not explained all that well. I suppose I will have to invest in a good book.

Comment: A book can certainly serve as a coherent introduction and tutorial. Ont the other hand XSLT 1.0 is more than ten years old, there are FAQ sites like http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/sect21.html and the archives of the XSL mailing list http://xsl.markmail.org/search/?q=mulberry#query:mulberry%20list%3Acom.mulberrytech.lists.xsl-list+page:1+state:facets are certainly worth reading.